# How can I create a choropleth from the 2010 census ZCTA shapefile using R and ggplot2?

Tags: shapefile, r, zip-codes, ggplot2, choropleth

I have created state and county choropleths in R using ggplot2.  The method I have used for this came from Winston Chang's "R Graphics Cookbook".  For those choropleths the map was already represented as a data.frame in R (as opposed to a shapefile).

I now need to create choropleths of the continental US at the ZIP code level.  The boundaries that I would like to use are the US Census ZCTA boundaries which you can download as a shapefile [here](http://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles2013/main) (select "ZIP Code Tabulation Areas" from the dropdown).  The shapefile is large, at over 500MB zipped.

I do not have a background in GIS, and attempted to create a choropleth from the shapefile in R using ggplot2 by following the advice on the ggplot2 wiki: [Plotting Polygon Shapefiles](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles).

However, when I attempt to follow the advice listed there the program just hangs:

```
require("rgdal") # requires sp, will use proj.4 if installed
require("maptools")
require("ggplot2")
require("plyr")

setwd("~/Desktop/tl_2013_us_zcta510")
zcta = readOGR(dsn=".", layer="tl_2013_us_zcta510")
zcta@data$id = rownames(zcta@data)

zcta.points = fortify(zcta, region="id")
```

The call to fortify hangs - even running it overnight it did not complete.  I have dug into the code for fortify a bit and can see the line that it causing it to hang (`coords <- ldply(model@polygons,fortify)`), but am not sure how to fix it.  I have also tried to follow the advice I have seen on numerous other websites about reading in shapefiles into R and ggplot2, but they don't seem to work for me either.  I can't tell if it is because of the size of this shapefile or for some other reason which I do not understand because of my lack of knowledge about GIS.

It would be great if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. My guess too. Try the subset suggested.  If that works you can either simplify the shape file and try again or loop through subsets and rbind them together.

To simplify I'd look at the thinnedSpatialPoly() function in the maptools library.  I don't have much guidance regarding the right threshold setting but something like

```
require("rgdal") # requires sp, will use proj.4 if installed
require("maptools")
require("ggplot2")
require("plyr")

Map <- readShapeSpatial('~/Desktop/tl_2013_us_zcta510/tl_2013_us_zcta510.shp')
#simplify the spatial polygon:  (not sure about ideal tolerance param)
zcta <- thinnedSpatialPoly(Map, tolerance=0.05)

zcta@data$id = rownames(zcta@data)

zcta.points = fortify(zcta, region="id")
```

Even if this works you will have to wait a long time for ggplot to generate a nationwide choropleth at zip level. Your code looks right to me

Comment: I did the subset suggested and then rbind'd them together as suggested.  The result is a large data.frame which takes ages to do any operations with (such as merging or rendering).  I like your suggestion of simplifying the shapefile.  I don't have prior GIS experience - can you explain how to do that?  My use case is for exploratory data analysis of business data (which will eventually be mashed up with census data - such as sales per capita).  So in my case precise boundaries are much less important being able to rapidly create multiple maps in a short amount of time.

Comment: Additionally, is there a way to remove ZCTAs from the shapefile that are not part of the continental US?  That would have the benefit of a) likely reducing the size of the shapefile quite a bit and b) making the map more analogous to the existing state and county maps already present in R's maps package

Comment: I'd inspect the dataframe embedded in the spatialpolygon 'zcta'.  Use head(zcta@data) and str(zcta@data) to get a sense of what is available within the zcta shapefile.  If you don't have anything obvious to subset with you might have to use another shapefile to mask the zcta one... I don't know how this is done in R (though I imagine it is possible).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not running out of memory? Did you try subsetting the data first?

```
zcta_subset <- zcta[as.integer(zcta@data$id) < 10,]
```

Comment: Thank you - subsetting seemed to work.  I then ran the loop over 1% of the shapefil at a time and rbind'd the final data.frame.  But the resulting data.frame is so large that it takes ages to work with.